# Cypress: what is the difference between `cy.contains` and `cy. findByText`

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-testing-library

`findByText` is from Cypress Testing Library
https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro

and `contains` comes with Cypress "natively"

I wonder what is the difference between them and when I should use one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

I think one difference could be found here: https://github.com/testing-library/cypress-testing-library#differences-from-dom-testing-library

> find* commands will fail if more than one element is found that matches the criteria which is not how built-in Cypress commands work, but is provided for closer compatibility to other Testing Libraries.

That's not how `contains()` works. From the docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Single-Element

> Only the first matched element will be returned

`contains()` also works with [preferences](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Preferences), e.g. `contains()` yields `<button>` element even if it's higher in the tree when the deeper element is e.g. `<span>`. So it prefers `<button>` elements over deeper elements if you don't pass a selector argument the command. There're other examples in the docs for this command.

---

So it seems to me now that `find*` commands in the Cypress Testing Library more closely resemble the behaviour of other testing libraries as it's said in the docs. With `contains()`, you perhaps need more knowledge about how it works so you get elements you want and not some other ones because e.g. you don't understand how this preference logic works.

Comment: Another difference is that if you chain contains, only the last element is retried: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html#Only-the-last-command-is-retried

Comment: Another nuance: `cy.contains('text')` is equivalent to `cy.findByText(/text/)` and not to `cy.findByText('text')` - notice the regexp.